# FormData JS vs standard php

Tags: javascript, php

short question.
I used the FormData Object in Javascript to send data to a php file, which saves it into a DB and sends a "ok" back.
Everything works fine BUT if I look into the Network Tab, I can see the data -> user, password etc.
Question would be, why bother using something like FormData if the data I send is visible in the browser, I could just use standard php you know, classic "style".

I just can't wrap my head around Javascript FormData Object, why bother using it, or do I use it in the wrong context? Where do you guys use it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also get the contents of a password textbox easily with input.value. Until the data is posted and sent through HTTPS, it's easy enough to read client-side.

Comment: Once your form goes 'on the wire' in transport to the backend, it will generally always take the same form of key=value pairs in a POST submit. The benefit of using FormData does not lie in how the data is transported, but rather in the ways the data can be manipulated client-side. As one of the end-points of the connection, you can see all the plaintext data, before it is optionally encrypted (if sent over https). The application layer (TLS over HTTP) takes care of data privacy along the way. The transport layer (TCP/IP in this case) ensures the integrity of the transmission.